# Python - Visual Studio -> coding across files question VS projects

Tags: python, visual-studio

Im kind of new to visual studio interface and python coding, poking around a little wth projects and have a question:

--> its possible to create a code in one file that creates the login to the apps for example and validates the credentials, storage the credential aprobation and then use those credentials stored in another file to valide if it can acess or not?

examples, suggestion and comment in these matter would be much apreciated thanks.

--> in addition if the initial file have for example a SQL conection reuse  that conection in another file for like example updating the records in the database referenced to that conection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very open question, but I'll try my best to answer it, assuming you're new to Python. What you are looking for is called [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) in python. By defining a module, e.g. `sqlconnection.py`, you can import this module by using a syntax like

```
from . import sqlconnection
```

This tells the module loader to look for the module `sqlconnection` in the current package. A package in Python is a set of modules in a directory that contains a file called `__init__.py`. So, in your case, creating the files

```
__init__.py
credentials.py
sqlconnection.py
app_part1.py
app_part2.py
```

allows you to reuse the sql connection and credentials from the module. The code statements at the module level are re-evaluated every time the module is reloaded (a module import does not reload a module - it only loads the module the first time it is referenced, so assigning e.g. the current connection means it will be reused across modules).

Python is a dynamic language. The constructs within a module (functions, classes) exist because there is code in the module to create them. Unlike static languages like C# or Java, loading a module will run the code to define the module. Because of this there is a possibility that a module gets reloaded and you end up with different instances of variables. This is typically a concern for library developers, not developers of end applications (as they should be aware of if they do `reload()` or not).

Comment: thanks, actually this clarify my question.